# What happens if a character has more than one gang?

Tags: apocalypse-world

Some improvement picks in Apocalypse World allow the same character to control more than a single gang. For example, Maestro'd can pick the security options of armed staff (providing *2-harm gang small 0-armor*) and (using a character improvement) "a real gang" (providing *3-harm gang small 1-armor*). Will the two gangs be treated as one bigger gang, or are they two separate entities? Can they be used in combat at the same time?

Answer (score 6):

I had a player who ended up in that exact situation in a game. We ended up agreeing that the gangs could be used separately, or together. When used together, they would count as a 2-harm gang medium 0-armor. So basically the same stats as the real gang (once you take size into account), but with more bodies to soak up casualties.

But that was in response to the in-game reality in my game. The staff were approximately a dozen armed non-combatants, while the "real gang" were three skilled mercenaries. So harm and armor got downgraded to the value of the largest group. If the real gang had also been a dozen strong, then I  might have gone with 3-harm gang medium 0-armor, with the 0-armor representing the squishiness of part of the gang.

In either case, the staff would generally get taken out first, and in the course of a fight, the Maestro'd might end up with just the "real gang" now using the "real gang" stat-line, representing the hardened survivors.

It all depends on how the fiction flows.

Answer (score 1):

Fiction first -- whatever the truth of these two groups is, is how it should play.

Part of the effectiveness of a gang is that they're working together as a group. How did the M'D get their non-staff gang? Are there relationships between the NPCs of the staff gang and the other gang? Do they trust each other, or mistrust each other?

If the groups are compatible enough that they can fight together, Rubberduck's stats seem generally sensible (except that a small gang plus three skilled mercenaries is, to me, still a small gang -- small gang is normally 10-20 people and medium gang is 30-40).